# How can I retrive the current text in a textbox if I have not yet saved

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

How can I get the current input of a textbox on a page without saving the information, e.g if i want to edit something without saving, how can I verify my input String is entered into the  textbox

**N.B** I am not allowed to save the form in this scenario.
The problem is getText(); against the box will just return an empty string because this must be essentially the saved value, but I haven't saved yet.

```
    public boolean checkTextBoxMaxLength(String Textbox, int maxLength) {
    int overMaxLength = maxLength + 1;
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < overMaxLength; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);

    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id(Textbox));
    ele.clear();

    ele = driver.findElement(By.id(Textbox));
    String maximum = ele.getAttribute("maxlength");
    System.out.println("Element maxlenght is: " +maximum);

    ele.sendKeys(output);
    String input = ele.getText();

    if (input.equals(output.substring(0,output.length()-1))) {  
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

In the above scenario, input will **always** equal " " as nothing has been saved, is there a simple solution to get the text as it currently exists pre-save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not returning an empty value because it is not saved, but because the input field does not have a text it has a value instead.

Try `element.getAttribute("value")`

Also check for alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input

Comment: Hi Niels, I didnt even think to try that as when I inspected the element it had no value attribute associated with it, safe to say it has one by default even if it not listed in the HTML?

Also, answer is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Yes @symon, value for text field attribute is by default even it its not listed in HTML. Thanks Niels for answer.